# Смещение текста на кнопке при нажатии на нее

Tags: java, android, button, textview, customview

Есть кастомная кнопка с тенью, которая при нажатии смещается вниз и влево (через `<selector>`).

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    android:text="Кнопка"
    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

@drawable/button_blue (unpressed & pressed):

```
<layer-list     
   <item
    android:right="3dp"
    android:top="3dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#c2bfbf" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/disabled"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>

<layer-list     
   <item
    android:right="3dp"
    android:top="3dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#c2bfbf" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/disabled"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Проблема в том, что текст с кнопки при этом остается на месте. Эффект нажатия получается неполный)
в `<selector'е>` текста не нашел как сделать смещение, интернет тоже на эту тему ничего не дал.

```
<selector>    
   <item android:color="@color/disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
   <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

**Вопрос:** как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст смещался вместе с бэком?

Comment: Если вы хотите просто сделать эффект нажатия, тем самым оживить нажатие или заменить стандартное, это далеко не лучший подход. Дело в том что на разных API, разные эффекты, а вы по сути перерисовываете их все, возможно вы этого и хотите, но если нет. Ваша проблема решается одной строчкой анимации scale, и разбавляется интерполяторами для достижения плавности и эффектов.

Comment: звучит здорово :) хоть и пока непонятно. Да, эффект нажатия.

Comment: У меня есть куча уроков по анимациям кнопок, я как только до компьютера дойду скину, там пару строчек добавить надо всего. Мб за это время сами найдете, примеров куча в сети.

Comment: уроки это хорошо) про scale+интерполятор анимацию кнопок не нагуглилось :-/

Comment: В данном случае эффект нажатия достигается селектором фона. И нужно всего сдвинуть текст при нажатии. Делать это анимацией мне кажется это как микроскопом гвозди забивать. Вот если бы нужно было кнопку при нажатии уменьшить и 10 раз вокруг себя крутануть, тогда да - без анимации не обойтись.

Comment: Я рад, что вы решили свою задачу. Я за оптимизацию и производительность кода, ваш случай проигрывает в том и др случае.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раньше можно было стиль в селектор засунуть. Сейчас только один вариант - расширить стандартный класс Button как-то вот так:

```
public class MButton extends Button {
    Integer padding_Left_orig = null;
    Integer padding_Top_orig = null;

    public MButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
        padding_Left_orig = left;
        padding_Top_orig = top;
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        int[] state = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);

        if (padding_Left_orig == null) padding_Left_orig = getPaddingLeft();
        if (padding_Top_orig == null) padding_Top_orig = getPaddingTop();

        for (int s : state) {
            if (s != android.R.attr.state_pressed) {
                super.setPadding(padding_Left_orig, padding_Top_orig,
                        getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom());
            } else {
                super.setPadding(padding_Left_orig - 10, padding_Top_orig + 10,
                        getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom());
                return state;
            }
        }

        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Работает, с одним маленьким недостатком - при первом нажатии текст прыгает вниз и влево. Пока не могу понять почему

Comment: Видимо padding_Left_orig на старте не инициализируется. Стоит отладчиком проверить вызывается ли setPadding и наверное инициализатор прописать в эти две переменные = 0

Comment: чо-т не получается разобраться. setPadding, да, не вызывается при инициализации. Но пока не могу найти решение.

Comment: Поменял код. Инициализация теперь при нажатии.

Comment: Тот же результат. При первом нажатии прыгает: я нажимаю, текст смещается как надо. Я отпускаю - текст остается на месте. При последующих нажатиях он работает нормально, но уже в том месте, где остался в первый раз.

Comment: На какой платформе тестируете ? Новые строчки в onTouchEvent добавили ? У меня таких проблем нет - нормально и ровно двигается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36304/discussion-between---and-abrog-petrovich).

Comment: проблема решена. Прыганье текста - недоработка в другой части кода. Александру еще раз спасибо.